# Get averages from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, average

Get averages from a python dictionary for example if i have the next dictionary:

```
students={'Dan':(5,8,8), 'Tim':(7), 'Richard':(9,9)}
```

And i would like to print de dictionary in the next form:

```
results={'Dan':(7), 'Tim':(7), 'Richard':(9)}
```

is there any function that i can use? Im new coding in python so dictionaries are a bit confusing for me.

Comment: For clarity, `(7)` isn't a thing in python. You've got integers `7` and integers in tuples `(7,)`. Do you want the sums to be in tuples?

Comment: Yes!, I'm trying to do it with tuples.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm fairly sure the OP thought the `(7)` you were referring to is the one in the input when he/she answered yes, or otherwise the data structure wouldn't make much sense. I'd let the OP edit the question on his/her own since the edit materially changes the expected data structure.

Comment: @blhsing - I made the change because of OP's comment just now. We should let OP decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the avg values will be a tuple element (I don't see any reason to do so but maybe I don't have enough context), try:

```
results={k: (sum(v)/len(v),) for k,v in students.items()}
```

Comment: The `tuple` constructor requires an iterable as an argument.

Comment: Instead of using a list literal just to convert it to a tuple, you can simply use a tuple literal: `(sum(v) / len(v),)`

Comment: @blhsing Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this but realized we had a problem summing a tuple of length 1. So you can do it this way.

```
results = {}
for k, v in students.items():
    print(v)
    if (isinstance(v, int)):
        results[k] = v
    else:
        results[k] = sum(v) / len(v)
```

Comment: it's not a tuple of length one, it's an int.  `(1, ) != (1)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. The other values are all tuples, but a single one is an int.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
result = {}
for k, v in students.items():
  if type(v) in [float, int]:
    result[k] = v
  else:
    result[k] = sum(v) / len(v)
```

Answer (score -1):

A pythonic solution would be to use dictionary comprehension to create the results dictionary.

```
def avg(l):
    return sum([l]) / len(l)

results = {key: (avg(val)) for (key, val) in students.items()}
```

You need brackets around the l in sum so the tuple is treated as a list. I would further change the data structure to a list instead of tuple.